# ASP.NET Core HttpRequest class has no BinaryRead method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET Core app, however they don't seem to have ported the entire HttpRequest class into Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc. This method is missing:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.binaryread(v=vs.90).aspx

Is there another way to do the same thing? I don't see a similar method to replace it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `MemoryStream` on the `Request` and retrieve the content of the `Body`.

Something like:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(2048))
{
    await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
    var rawData = ms.ToArray();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the Read() method to get the byte array directly

```
byte[] LocalStorage = new byte[2048];
Request.Body.Read(LocalStorage, 0, LocalStorage.Length);
```